# Compile common C files for different targets with different CFLAGS

Tags: c, makefile, compilation, cmake, gnu-make

I have a scenario where I need to use the same C files for building the different targets with different CFLAGS.

Lets say like I have common1.c common2.c common3.c common files.

Target1 has other files a.c b.c and CFLAGS as CFLAGS1
Target2 has other files 1.c 2.c and CFLAGS as CFLAGS2

Target1 needs common files compiled with CFLAGS1
Target2 needs common files compiled with CFLAGS2.

How can I do that.

Thanks in Advance
Venkatesh

Comment: Do you use CMake? Or why "cmake" tag?

Answer (score 0):

So I think this part of the documentation is what you're after:
https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html

"There is one more special feature of target-specific variables: when you define a target-specific variable that variable value is also in effect for all prerequisites of this target, and all their prerequisites, etc. (unless those prerequisites override that variable with their own target-specific variable value). So, for example, a statement like this:"

```
prog : CFLAGS = -g
prog : prog.o foo.o bar.o
```

It's important to read through the page, since there are some implications of requiring such a recipe (or just executing it)